# Is There any way to simplify this htaccess code?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please let me know,

if there is any way to simplify this htaccess code into 2 line.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/demo1/ordercheck$ http://www.mywebsite.com/demo1/ordercheck.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/demo2/ordercheck$ http://www.mywebsite.com/demo2/ordercheck.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/demo3/ordercheck$ http://www.mywebsite.com/demo3/ordercheck.php [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/demo([1-3])/ordercheck$ http://www.mywebsite.com/demo$1/ordercheck.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you @Sahil Gulati,

but i want the "demo1"  folder name to be fully dynamic which could have lowercase letter and numbers. (eg. dev01, demo02, etc.)

Comment: can you help on this

Comment: you can use  `^/([a-z]+)([\d]+)/ordercheck$` `http://www.mywebsite.com/$1$2/ordercheck.php`  $1 will contain word $2 will contain numerals